# How to add sorting to a custom column on index in activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activeadmin

I have these associations:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_events
  has_many :users, through: :users_events
end

class UsersEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_events
  has_many :events, through: :users_events
end
```

In activeadmin I display my index page as:

```
index do
  # some columns
  column :total_participants do |event|
    event.users.count
  end
  # other columns
end
```

Doing like this, the sorting is absent in this column. If I do this: `column(:user_count, sortable: 'users') { |event| event.users.count }`, the sorting appears, but the query seems to be wrong: `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users' in 'order clause': SELECT  'events'.* FROM 'events' ORDER BY 'users' desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0`

So, what is the best way of adding sorting to a custom column, and what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to use this column multiple times, it's better to `cache` it.
To do so, it's better to add a new column to `events` called `users_count` with a default of `0` and increment it each time you have a new user:

migration:

```
add_column :events, :users_count, default: 0
add_index :events, :users_count
```

model:

```
class UsersEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
  after_create -> {Event.increment_counter(:users_count, self.event.id)}
end
```

I'm also not sure why your model is called `UsersEvent` not `EventUser`